# Choose default instance under ambiguous types

Tags: haskell

Is there a Haskell language extension for the type class method to "use the only potential instance available"?

I want to compile the following

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}

class Foo a r where
 foo :: a -> r 


instance Foo a (Bool -> a) where
  foo x _ = x 

-- This compiles 
-- bar :: Int -> Bool

-- This does not  
bar :: a -> Bool  
bar _ = True 


use :: Bool 
use = bar $ foo _5 True
  where
    _5 :: Int 
    _5 = 5
```

Now I get the following error:

```
     No instance for (Foo Int (Bool -> r0))
  (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
  arising from a use of ‘foo’
The type variable ‘r0’ is ambiguous
Note: there is a potential instance available:
  instance Foo a (Bool -> a) -- Defined at tests/pos/Fixme.hs:9:10
```

But since there is only one potential instance available, is there a way to force ghc to use that instance? Or is there a way to declare some instance as a default instance when types are ambiguous?

Comment: This typeclass + instance makes me cringe. Are you sure you are expressing the right thing here?

Answer (score 2):

The standard trick is to make your instance more polymorphic, thus:

```
instance (a ~ b, bool ~ Bool) => Foo a (bool -> b) where
    foo x _ = x
```

This precludes you from writing other function instances, but makes it clear what types to use when a function instance is wanted. You will need to turn on the `TypeFamilies` extension to do this. In your specific case you may be able to get away with just `instance a ~ b => Foo a (Bool -> b)`, which would allow further function instances with other argument types, at the cost of more frequent ambiguity errors.

See [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913744/791604) for some more explanation of this trick.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I can leave the `Bool` as is! The following is enough!


     `instance (a~b) => Foo a (Bool -> b) where foo x _ = x`

Comment: I am trying to understand why this trick works: 
Is it that since the instance is so general, first the instance is "accepted" by type checker and _then_ the constraint `a~b` is checked?
In my initial example, what prevents `r` to be instantiated to `Int`.

Comment: @Niki Correct: instance contexts (things to the left of `=>`) are ignored while choosing an instance. In your example, nothing prevents `r` from being instantiated to `Int` -- but nothing forces it, either; since somebody could potentially come along later and define an instance for e.g. `instance Foo Int (Bool -> ())`, it is not clear that the existing instance is the right one to choose. Even though it's the only one that matches given the current modules being compiled, the open world assumption means that further compilation units could be added later.